# C# Rounding a negative exponential double value

Tags: c#, math, double, rounding, exponential

I tried everything, but not able to round up a negative double value with a very long decimal value(exponential) to 6 decimal.

```
string str = "-1.7976931348623157E+308";
double d = double.Parse(str);
d = Math.Round(d, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
string str2 = d.ToString();
```

I want to result as -1.797693, as simple as that!

Comment: You understand that `"-1.7976931348623157E+308"` is `-1.797693` with 307 zeroes in front of it, correct?  How do you expect rounding to bring it to -1.797693?

Comment: C# has a Decimal value, which you should be using. If you just want it formatted for output you could use d.ToString("#.######");

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Yes, I do understand. Let me simply this question - My requirement says that value should get displayed as -1.797693. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @JoeSwindell - That will display "-179769313486232000000..." 308 zeros. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, as LittleBobbyTables suggests, there's no way `1.xxE+308` is going to round to `1.xx`. But assuming you didn't mean that, and you're just trying to structure your output:

```
string str2 = d.ToString("E6");
```

Where the number in `E6` is the amount of numbers you'd like to display before the E notation.

For your example above, `str2` will have the value `"-1.797693E+308"`.

If you do actually need your value rounded (and I'm not really sure why you would - why throw away precision? It's not going to get in your way), you should keep your `Round` call as it stands above.

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned above...My requirements says that value should get displayed as "-1.797693". What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @user2502938 That doesn't make any sense - there's no real way to do that because there's no logic to stripping an exponent off a scientifically-notated value. What does "-1.797693" mean in relation to the same number that has 308 additional zeroes? What are you even trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You this code I wrote to round based on number of [significant digits](http://www.usca.edu/chemistry/genchem/sigfig.htm):

```
/// <summary>
/// Format a number with scientific exponents and specified sigificant digits.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">The value to format</param>
/// <param name="significant_digits">The number of siginicant digits to show</param>
/// <returns>The fomratted string</returns>
public static string Sci(this double x, int significant_digits)
{
    //Check for special numbers and non-numbers
    if (double.IsInfinity(x)||double.IsNaN(x)||x==0)
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }
    // extract sign so we deal with positive numbers only
    int sign=Math.Sign(x);
    x=Math.Abs(x);
    // get scientific exponent, 10^3, 10^6, ...
    int sci=(int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(x, 10)/3)*3;
    // scale number to exponent found
    x=x*Math.Pow(10, -sci);
    // find number of digits to the left of the decimal
    int dg=(int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(x, 10))+1;
    // adjust decimals to display
    int decimals=Math.Min(significant_digits-dg, 15);
    // format for the decimals
    string fmt=new string('0', decimals);
    if (sci==0)
    {
        //no exponent
        return string.Format("{0}{1:0."+fmt+"}",
            sign<0?"-":string.Empty,
            Math.Round(x, decimals));
    }
    int index=sci/3+6;
    // with 10^exp format
    return string.Format("{0}{1:0."+fmt+"}e{2}",
        sign<0?"-":string.Empty,
        Math.Round(x, decimals),
        sci);
}
```

Such that `Debug.WriteLine((-1.7976931348623157E+308).Sci(7));` produces `-179.7693e306`

Comment: Note that apparently he doesn't want `179.7693e306` but `179.7693`, no exponent. No idea why, but maybe you've got something in your pocket for that too.

Comment: @ja72 - Thanks for sharing the code. Yes, as furkle mentioned I need this as 179.7693. 

But I don't understand why everybody is questioning the requirement? If requirement says we need it, we need it...right? We know we will be loosing all decimal details, but that's how we want it.